# plyr split_indices function crashes for long vectors

Tags: r, segmentation-fault, plyr

I am trying to run `acast` function from the package `reshape2` on a large data set, and getting the program crash. I was able to localize this problem:

```
library(plyr)
n <- 15784000
g <- 1:n
split_indices(g, n) # NOTE for copy/pasters:
                    # this may result in an abort and R exit
```

I am getting the following error message:

```
*** caught segfault *** address 0x7ffffc3c44f0, cause 'memory not mapped'

Traceback:
 1: .Call("split_indices", group, as.integer(n))
 2: split_indices(g, n)
```

If I reduce the value of n:

```
n <- 3946000
```

then the error message is different:

```
Error: segfault from C stack overflow
```

The R system I am using:

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 2.15.2 (2012-10-26)
Platform: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Package: plyr_1.8
```

Is this a distribution/build problem? Can it be fixed by appropriate choice of build parameters and how?

Comment: I was under the impression that `split_indices` wasn't an exported function, which would imply that you probably shouldn't be using it anyway.

Comment: reproducible with plyr_1.8 on Ubuntu 10.04 with 32-bit R Under development (unstable) (2012-12-14 r61321). I would say this *definitely* belongs on https://github.com/hadley/plyr/issues

Comment: @joran, `split_indices` does seem to be exported from plyr, at least in version 1.8 ...

Comment: @BenBolker You're right, I forgot this computer was running an older version.

Comment: There was a fix to https://github.com/hadley/plyr/blob/master/src/split-numeric.c 3 months ago to stop a different kind of segfault problem.  I wonder whether there is some sort of integer overflow problem going on here?

Comment: Unrelated comment: Looks like you've deleted your [subclass question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25787313/calling-subclasses-from-derived-class-in-python), but I'd like to share my solution: http://ideone.com/B8sXVm
I will delete this comment after a while. ;-)

Comment: Whoops! I noticed that issue with your code was the `__class__` call inside class method, so my solution is an overkill I guess. :)